# Cannot pass @SortDefault Sort object into controller method?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-commons

It is stated in the documentation of `@SortDefault` that

> Annotation to define the default Sort options to be used when
>   injecting a Sort instance into a controller handler method.

But the fact is, I got this exception:

> Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.domain.Sort]: No
>   default constructor found; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.()

Did I miss something here?

```
void download(WebRequest request, HttpSession session,
      @RequestParam(value = "fields",
          defaultValue = "id,hostname,networkId,customerId") String[] visibleProperties,
      @SortDefault("hostname") Sort sort, HttpServletResponse response) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably missed an `@EnableSpringDataWebSupport` in your configuration.

Comment: Thanks. For my case, I need to put `<bean class="org.springframework.data.web.SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver" id="sortResolver"/>` inside `<mvc:argument-resolvers>`